# What is it called when novels don't start at the beginning of the storyline?

Tags: terminology, literary-techniques

Reef, by Romesh Gunesekera, essentially starts in the middle of the character storyline - what is the literary term name for this?

Answer (score 3):

There's a term borrowed from Latin for this: *in medias res*

> in or into the middle of a narrative or plot

(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20medias%20res))

Literally translated, it means "into the middle of things".

It's quite old; according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_medias_res#First_use_of_the_phrase), it was first used by the Roman poet Horatius more than two millennia ago. But it is well understood within the context of literature, and used for books as well for performances.

Comment: The locus for this well-known Horatian tag is *Ars Poetica (De Arte Poetica liber / Epistola ad Pisones)* 147–48: [Latin](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0064%3Acard%3D125)/[English](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0065%3Acard%3D125). Milton references it in the [Argument](http://www.bartleby.com/4/401.html) to the first book of the second edition of *Paradise Lost,* writing “the poem hastes *into the midst of things,”* and Pope uses the same formula in *The Dunciad.*

Comment: Horace is recommending that aspiring poets follow Homeric precedent in starting in the midst of things rather than starting with the original cause, which he identifies as the egg from which Helen was hatched.